# Bracketed values with Mathjax

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

I would like to be able to produce something like this with Mathjax:

[image: bracket]

i.e. two values bracketed together, one value on its own in the middle and two more values bracketed together.
Does anyone know the way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following:

$$\left.\begin{array}{c}
5\\
6
\end{array}
\right] \quad 2\quad \left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2
\end{array}\right.$$

is produced by

```
$$\left.\begin{array}{c}
5\\
6
\end{array}
\right] \quad 2\quad \left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2
\end{array}\right.$$
```

You can make the number smaller and/or add space by including blank lines, e.g.
$$\left.\begin{array}{c}
5\\
\\
6
\end{array}
\right]\quad 2\quad \left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
\\2
\end{array}\right.$$
just adds a blank line in the middle of the two arrays.

Comment: Thanks very much (+1) The first version is ideal.

Comment: @PeterPhipps: I trust you understand what the commands are doing, so that you can modify it at will. If you are unsure, just let me know.

Comment: Mathjax has support for the optional height argument to `\\ ` , e.g. `\\[2em]` adds 2em of space

Answer (score 6):

It isn't pretty, but:

$$
\left.
\begin{matrix} 5\\[5ex] 6 \end{matrix}
\right]
\begin{matrix} \\ 2 \\ \\ \end{matrix}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 \\[5ex] 2
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

```
$$
\left.
\begin{matrix} 5\\[5ex] 6 \end{matrix}
\right]
\begin{matrix} \\ 2 \\ \\ \end{matrix}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 \\[5ex] 2
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$
```